# C++ map with class pointer gives error while compiling

Tags: c++

I have a map with string and an class pointer.
I am from JAVA so please guide me.

```
class Client {

public:
    static map<string, Client*> CLIENTS;
    Client(string dir);
    static Client* get_client(string name);
    virtual ~Client();
};
```

My get_client method is

```
Client* Client::get_client(string name) {
       map<string, Client*>::iterator it = CLIENTS.find(name);
}
```

gives me the error below

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Client::CLIENTS", referenced from:
      Client::get_client(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in client.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If your `get_client`'s body is exactly as you posted, then it's senseless

Comment: @borisbn i removed a lot of code while trying to locating the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `CLIENTS` which you have only declared. So outside of `class Client{`, in your `clients.cpp` file add

```
 std::map<std::string, Client*> Client::CLIENTS;
```

BTW, I find the name `CLIENTS` quite confusing. Maybe it should be `client_dict`

Don't forget to compile with debugging information and all warnings, e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux. Improve your code till no warnings are given (your `get_client` will get some). And learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

Comment: I have added std::map<std::string, Client*> CLIENTS; in the cpp file still i am getting same issue

Comment: Sorry, that should be `client::CLIENTS`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
map<string, Client*> Client::CLIENTS;
```

to `cpp` file.
And do not omit `std::` prefix before STL classes. Especially in header